# How to disable auto creation of curly brackets({}) in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I write

```
if(true)
{
```

eclipse auto-completes it to

```
if(true)
{
    //cursor here
}
```

Which gets annoying when I want to write an else or else if. Any way to disable it?

Comment: I think so, try this - http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~dulimarh/CS163/EclipseSettings.html

Comment: Doesn't it jump to the closing `}` when you type `}`?

Comment: I have exactly the opposite problem... It won't auto-close the curly brace whereas I ticked the box in the Preferences window.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From Eclipse's main window, choose <kbd>Window</kbd> and then <kbd>Preferences</kbd>. Then choose <kbd>Java</kbd>, <kbd>Editor</kbd> and then <kbd>Typing</kbd> to get the following screen:

[image]

and un-check <kbd>{Braces}</kbd>.

Tested on Eclipse Helios.

Comment: I've done this, but Eclipse is still auto-completing braces and strings. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: @JaredNielsen: Same here, any fixes yet?

Comment: If not working for you, some things to check. When changing settings, click 'Apply' before 'Ok'. There are multiple editors, e.g. for different programming languages.  Choose the one(s) you want to change. If all else fails, try restarting Eclipse. Hope this helps.