# Eclipse adds extra braces

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

While editing java and javascript, code in eclipse. Whenever I add an opening brace eclipse automatically adds a closing brace after that. Then on pressing enter eclipse adds yet another closing brace. This is quite annoying. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: This may helpfult to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374119/how-to-disable-auto-creation-of-curly-brackets-in-eclipse